# facebook deep linking (app links) to ios app doesn't work

Tags: ios, facebook, deep-linking

I can't figure out how to make facebook, when sharing url with my website, to show "Open in the My app" button. (like in documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/ios)

I'm adding to the header

```
<meta property="al:ios:url" content="myapp://" />
<meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="id..." />
<meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="App name" />
```

Deep linking button is switched on in the dev.facebook settings.

My app have myapp:// in the schema and is opened with such a url.

Need i something more?

Comment: Have you added the bundle id to your apps settings on FB?

Comment: yes. bundle id should be equal to app url schema or what?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? Im facing the same issue. I have all the metatags in my webpage, but Facebook app show the page in it's internal browser instead of redirecting the user to my app.

Comment: no, sorry. Would be happy to hear solution too

Comment: Hello @adsurbum, have solved your prob.? If yes then need some help from you. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[image]
Bundle ID: same bundle id as in your app (Info.plist)

URL Scheme is the name only, no :// (In your Info.plist under URL Schemes)

iPhone/iPad store is the id in your iTunes link like the following:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/app/appname/id55####003?ls=1&mt=8
```

Comment: and what is Url Scheme Suffix? Do i need it?

Comment: You DEFINITELY need the URL Scheme suffix if you want to open your app from Facebook, that is how you open apps from other apps. This works for me yes, you need to set up the correct URL schemes in your project, then you need to test it with Safari then enter it in FB. eg. myappname://app, this wont work if you havent set it up in your project.

Comment: i can open myapp:// in safari (it opens the app). Should Url Scheme Suffix be 'myapp'? right? Now, if i putting inside the <head> tag of the site.com metadata <meta property="al:ios:url" content="myapp://" /> ... and posting in the facebook the url (site.com), it should work as deep linking, yes? thanks :)

Comment: Sorry I cant help you any further than iOS, I have like NO background in web, so sorry. Goodluck!

Comment: This answer looks good, do you know any way to test this without releasing App Store update? Should it work from the Xcode build?